# Using a Simple Dependency Injection in PHP

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am working on a project where I am trying to implement a simple dependency injection. I implemented the class below, but am not sure if it's the best practice or should I go with some of the DI Containers around?

The Container Class

```
namespace App\Includes;

class Container {
  private $class=[];

  protected $config = [
  'user' => 'App\Models\User',
  'template' => 'Library\Template',
  'database' => 'Library\Database'
  ];


 public function getClass($name) {
    if (!isset($this->class[$name])) {
        $this->class[$name] = new $this->config[$name]();
    }

    return $this->class[$name];
 } 
}
```

The Controller

```
 namespace App;

 use App\Includes\Container as Container;

class Controller{
protected $template;
protected $database;

  public function __construct(Container $container){
    $this->database = $container->getClass('database');
    $this->template = $container->getClass('template');

 }

 }
```

Here I initiate the app (The $controller is supplied by the router)

```
$container = new App\Includes\Container();
$obj = new $controller($container);
```

Comment: `$obj = new $controller($container);` might be vulnerable https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unsafe_use_of_Reflection

Comment: I have a router class that matches based on url before calling the controller class. So user supplied values are not used to instantiate the class directly.